# Outlook add-in does not return message from dialog on MacOS

Tags: macos, outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am developing Outlook add-in and I am displaying dialog using office API:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, dialogOptions, function (result) {
   loginDialog = result.value;
   loginDialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, receiveLoginMessage);
   loginDialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogEventReceived, loginDialogClosed);
   event.completed();
});
```

On Windows everything works well both on desktop app and browsers (including Chrome). However, when I want to run it on Outlook for Mac it does not return a message from dialog.

Dialog is displayed, it has functionality, but when I want to send the message it stays open. Vorlon.js throws this in my MainWindow:

> messages received cannot be handlered.
>   Message:{"dialogMessage":{"messageType":0,"messageContent":"{ …here my content... }”}}

Any idea if I can handle this?

Comment: We are looking into this issue.
Meanwhile, you can pass the data as:
Office.context.ui.messageParent("{'dialogMessage':{'messageType':0,'messageContent':'{ …here my content... }'}}");

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility. I want my Addin to work on all the platforms. How can I receive the message then?